# Check if pathlib.Path is a file or directory without pathlib.Path exist on directory

Tags: python

How to tell if pathlib.Path is a file or dir path without being physically present on disk.
I do not want to check if the actual file exists on the disk. Something like this.

```
from pathlib import Path

home = Path.home()

def function_to_differentiate_file_and_dir(filepath):
    return 'file' is filepath is file
    return 'dir' if filepath is dir


assert function_to_differentiate_file_and_dir(home / 'test.txt') == 'file'
assert function_to_differentiate_file_and_dir(home / 'test.txt') == 'file'
```

What have you tried?:

```
def function_to_differentiate_file_and_dir(filepath):
    return 'file' if filepath.suffix else 'dir'
```

Comment: Something like `temp/file_or.folder` could be a file or a folder. But if it's not there you can't know.

Comment: I agree. So there's no way, right except checking manually the known file extensions?

Comment: Even that will fail. There is no reason why a folder couldn't be called "test.txt".

Comment: And much more common thing: common file with no extension, like `/bin/ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize my and others' comments: it's not possible.  There is nothing in a path string that can indicate file or dir with any reliability (except trailing [back]slash, but it's stripped by `pathlib.Path` object):

```
>>> pathlib.Path('/var/')
PosixPath('/var')
```

You could try devising some heuristics for your particular use case, based on file extensions your code might encounter with `pathlib.Path.suffix` that you've mentioned, but in a general case there are pretty obvious issues with that approach:

- `/home/user/documents.txt/` might very well exist (being a directory)
- on UNIX-like systems files with no extension are ubiquitous, take e.g. `/bin/cat`